# Google Sheets - Button to export sheet into xls with values and formats only - not formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets file with tens of sheets into it.
In one of those I need to create a button or a link to export the content in that specific sheet to a xls format, with the values and formats only, not formulas. How could I do that using Google Script?

The best I managed to do is to create a macro that goes into `File > Publish to the web`, creates a "web file" and writes the link of it in the sheet. I applied a shortcut to the macro, so even not being a button it is kinda effective. However I need to download the sheet named "Result" to Excel, so this web file solution didn't solve it.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

OK. It's a trivial task.

Let's assume you need to export 'COUNTIF' sheet from the book with id 'ABSD1234'

```
function runSheet() {
  var spec = ['COUNTIF'];

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    'ABSD1234'
  ).copy('tmp');

  spec.forEach(function(sheetName) {
    var dr = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();
    dr.setValues(dr.getValues());
  });
  spreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) {
    if (spec.indexOf(sheet.getName()) < 0) spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet);
  });
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
  var file = exportSpreadsheetToFile_(spreadsheetId, 'xlsx');
  DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId).setTrashed(true);
  return file;
}
```

You can get `exportSpreadsheetToFile_` from [the snippet](https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/tree/master/snippets/standalone/export_spreadsheet_to).

After this you get file on your Drive with its reference in `file`.

Comment: I got an error: "Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (linha 118).", then I've changed 'ABSD1234' to my spreadsheet name, but the error kept happening. Any ideas?

Comment: btw, line 118 looks like this: "var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(". In the apps script screen it says "invalid value in line 118"